# Blinder-Oaxaca decomposition, logistic regression and unbalanced dataset: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, decomposition, variance-decomposition, blinder-oaxaca

I have a binary `y` outcome, a dummy variable `gender` for gender, and a set of covariates `x` (including some factor variables converted into dummies, excluding one dummy in each of the factor variables) and a set of control dummies `cdummies` (they come from one single factor variable, I have excluded one dummy) for which I want the `oaxaca` package to apply the Gardeazabal and Ugidos (2004) correction.

I am estimating a logistic regression of `Y` on `gender` and the covariates `x` and `cdummies`.

Then, using the R [oaxaca](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/oaxaca/index.html) package, I am decomposing the difference in the outcome among the two genders.

Given:
`f = y ~ x + cdummies | gender | cdummies`

The function I am calling is:

```
results <- oaxaca(f, 
                  data = df, 
                  R = 1000,
                  reg.fun = glm,
                  family = binomial(link="logit"))
```

The problem is that, after the calculations have finished, it gives me a lot of warnings of the type:

```
glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

I think this is due to my dataset being unbalanced: only 0.5% of the observations get the outcome.

This, I think, causes the algorithm, during bootstrapping of the standard error, to randomly pick only observations for which the outcome never happens.

How can I fix this problem?

One solution could be oversampling, but in this case the difference in the probability of the outcome occurring would turn out to be 0.

Another solution would be stratified sampling for the bootstrapped sample, but I would have to modify the package.

How can I fix this?

Or can I just ignore the warnings?

EDIT: I am able to fit the two regressions separately for the two genders without errors:

```
fit_males <- glm(ftest, 
                 data=df[df$d_gender_female==0,], 
                 family=binomial)

fit_females <- glm(ftest, 
                 data=df[df$d_gender_female==1,], 
                 family=binomial)
```

However `ftest` is a bit different than `f`.

In fact `ftest = y ~ gender + x + cdummies`

While `f = y ~ x + cdummies | gender | cdummies`

EDIT2: Frequency table asked in the comments:

```
> table(df$y, df$gender)

         0      1
  0 194276  88007
  1    995    237
```

Comment: Are you able to fit the two logistic models for males and females separately without this issue arising?

Comment: @awhug that's a very very good question, I will try shortly. Thank you very much

Comment: @awhug Yes I am. I have edited the question

Comment: I have further edited the question to fix typos and explain what formulas I am using exactly

Comment: Provide a frequency table of $y \times$ gender.

Comment: @FrankHarrell I have edited the question to provide the requested frequency table. Thank you very much.

Comment: I admit I haven't read their paper, but if you want to 'correct' for gender, can't you just add an interaction with `x` and perhaps with the dummy variable in an ordinary GLM?

Comment: @FransRodenburg in this post the problem is not to correct for gender, the problem is that I get `glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred` warnings. Or at least I didn't quite understand your question.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Any insight on my frequency table? :)

Comment: Looks like the effective sample size is large enough to estimate all of your parameters.

Comment: Oaxaca decomposition for non-linear models is another story. I think you're missing something but I am happy to be wrong. See: https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.05417